# Limiting the shown area for a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3, wms, tools

I am new to QGIS so im not that experienced with the program. I want to create a GeoPackage with various WMS and shapefile information sources for a small area, but all my source files have displayed data for the whole country. Is there a QGIS function to limit the displayed area of the source files to a set one? I can´t find any information online.

Comment: There are tools in QGIS to clip both vector and raster data. Have a look at the documentation. 

https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html

https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html

Comment: If your QGIS is a late enough version and you have or can create a polygon that delineates your small area, you could use the inverted polygon option to mask (fully or partial transparency) all the layers that are below the polygon layer in the layer list panel.